# Cassandra Spring No Converter Found Capable of Converting from Type Instant to type Long

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, cassandra, spring-data

Am getting a No converter found capable of converting from type Instant to type Long while using Spring and Cassandra.

I have 2 Instant fields writtenDate (in the object primary key) and hotelAddedDate in the object.  However, I do not have any Long fields; thus, I am a little confused.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this error?

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.time.Instant] to type [java.lang.Long]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:322)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:195)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:175)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ConvertingPropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(ConvertingPropertyAccessor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ConvertingPropertyAccessor.getProperty(ConvertingPropertyAccessor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.getWriteValue(MappingCassandraConverter.java:771)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.writeInternal(MappingCassandraConverter.java:518)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.writeInternal(MappingCassandraConverter.java:513)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.write(MappingCassandraConverter.java:484)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.StatementFactory.insert(StatementFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.doInsert(CassandraTemplate.java:674)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:664)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.SimpleCassandraRepository.save(SimpleCassandraRepository.java:96)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:639)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy199.save(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy199.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.saathratri.tajvote.service.impl.CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstNameServiceImpl.save(CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstNameServiceImpl.java:36)
    at com.saathratri.tajvote.service.impl.CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstNameServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$da12f07b.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:783)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:64)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)
    at com.saathratri.tajvote.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:105)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:634)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:624)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:72)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at com.saathratri.tajvote.service.impl.CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstNameServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eda9c521.save(<generated>)
    at com.saathratri.tajvote.web.rest.CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstNameResource.createCustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstName(CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstNameResource.java:77)
    at com.saathratri.tajvote.web.rest.CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstNameResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d91d43fd.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
...
```

Here is my CQL for creating the table in Cassandra:

```
create table customer_reviews_by_hotel_and_last_name_and_first_name (
 hotel_id uuid,
 last_name text,
 first_name text, 
 written_date timestamp,
 review_id timeuuid,
 customer_id uuid,
 customer_email_addresses set<text>,
 customer_phone_numbers set<text>,
 added_source text,
 main_star_rating tinyint,
 comments text,
 enjoyed_stay boolean,
 would_recommend boolean,
 hotel_added_date timestamp,
 hotel_name text,
 hotel_email text,
 hotel_phone_number text,
 primary key((hotel_id), last_name, first_name, written_date, review_id))
with clustering order by (last_name desc, first_name desc, written_date desc, review_id asc);
```

This is my primary key class:

```
package com.saathratri.tajvote.domain;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.PrimaryKeyType;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CassandraType;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKeyClass;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKeyColumn;

@PrimaryKeyClass
public class CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstNameId
  implements java.io.Serializable {

  @PrimaryKeyColumn(
    name = "hotel_id",
    ordinal = 0,
    type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED
  )
  @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.UUID)
  private UUID hotelId;

  @PrimaryKeyColumn(
    name = "last_name",
    ordinal = 1,
    type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED
  )
  @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.TEXT)
  private String lastName;

  @PrimaryKeyColumn(
    name = "first_name",
    ordinal = 2,
    type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED
  )
  @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.TEXT)
  private String firstName;

  @PrimaryKeyColumn(
    name = "written_date",
    ordinal = 3,
    type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED
  )
  @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.BIGINT)
  private Instant writtenDate;

  @PrimaryKeyColumn(
    name = "review_id",
    ordinal = 4,
    type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED
  )
  @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.UUID)
  private UUID reviewId;

  public CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstNameId() {}

  public CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstNameId(
    UUID hotelId,
    String lastName,
    String firstName,
    Instant writtenDate,
    UUID reviewId
  ) {
    this.hotelId = hotelId;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.writtenDate = writtenDate;
    this.reviewId = reviewId;
  }

  public UUID getHotelId() {
    return this.hotelId;
  }

  public void setHotelId(UUID hotelId) {
    this.hotelId = hotelId;
  }

  public String getLastName() {
    return this.lastName;
  }

  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
  }

  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  public Instant getWrittenDate() {
    return this.writtenDate;
  }

  public void setWrittenDate(Instant writtenDate) {
    this.writtenDate = writtenDate;
  }

  public UUID getReviewId() {
    return this.reviewId;
  }

  public void setReviewId(UUID reviewId) {
    this.reviewId = reviewId;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstNameId)) {
      return false;
    }

    CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstNameId customerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstNameId = (CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstNameId) o;
    return (
      Objects.equals(
        hotelId,
        customerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstNameId.hotelId
      ) &&
      Objects.equals(
        lastName,
        customerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstNameId.lastName
      ) &&
      Objects.equals(
        firstName,
        customerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstNameId.firstName
      ) &&
      Objects.equals(
        writtenDate,
        customerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstNameId.writtenDate
      ) &&
      Objects.equals(
        reviewId,
        customerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstNameId.reviewId
      )
    );
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(hotelId, lastName, firstName, writtenDate, reviewId);
  }

  // prettier-ignore
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstNameId{" +
            ", hotelId='" + getHotelId() + "'" +
            ", lastName='" + getLastName() + "'" +
            ", firstName='" + getFirstName() + "'" +
            ", writtenDate='" + getWrittenDate() + "'" +
            ", reviewId='" + getReviewId() + "'" +
            "}";
    }
}
```

This my domain class:

```
package com.saathratri.tajvote.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CassandraType;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKey;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Table;

/**
 * A CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstName.
 */
@Table("customer_reviews_by_hotel_and_last_name_and_first_name")
public class CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstName
  implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @PrimaryKey
  private CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstNameId id;

  @Column("customer_id")
  @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.UUID)
  private UUID customerId;

  @Column("customer_email_addresses")
  @CassandraType(
    type = CassandraType.Name.SET,
    typeArguments = CassandraType.Name.TEXT
  )
  private Set<String> customerEmailAddresses;

  @Column("customer_phone_numbers")
  @CassandraType(
    type = CassandraType.Name.SET,
    typeArguments = CassandraType.Name.TEXT
  )
  private Set<String> customerPhoneNumbers;

  @Column("added_source")
  @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.TEXT)
  private String addedSource;

  @Column("main_star_rating")
  @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.TINYINT)
  private Integer mainStarRating;

  @Column("comments")
  @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.TEXT)
  private String comments;

  @Column("enjoyed_stay")
  @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.BOOLEAN)
  private Boolean enjoyedStay;

  @Column("would_recommend")
  @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.BOOLEAN)
  private Boolean wouldRecommend;

  @Column("hotel_added_date")
  @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.BIGINT)
  private Instant hotelAddedDate;

  @Column("hotel_name")
  @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.TEXT)
  private String hotelName;

  @Column("hotel_email")
  @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.TEXT)
  private String hotelEmail;

  @Column("hotel_phone_number")
  @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.TEXT)
  private String hotelPhoneNumber;

  public CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstNameId getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstNameId id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstName id(
    CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstNameId id
  ) {
    this.id = id;
    return this;
  }

  // jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here
  public UUID getCustomerId() {
    return this.customerId;
  }

  public CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstName customerId(
    UUID customerId
  ) {
    this.setCustomerId(customerId);
    return this;
  }

  public void setCustomerId(UUID customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
  }

  public Set<String> getCustomerEmailAddresses() {
    return this.customerEmailAddresses;
  }

  public CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstName customerEmailAddresses(
    Set<String> customerEmailAddresses
  ) {
    this.setCustomerEmailAddresses(customerEmailAddresses);
    return this;
  }

  public void setCustomerEmailAddresses(Set<String> customerEmailAddresses) {
    this.customerEmailAddresses = customerEmailAddresses;
  }

  public Set<String> getCustomerPhoneNumbers() {
    return this.customerPhoneNumbers;
  }

  public CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstName customerPhoneNumbers(
    Set<String> customerPhoneNumbers
  ) {
    this.setCustomerPhoneNumbers(customerPhoneNumbers);
    return this;
  }

  public void setCustomerPhoneNumbers(Set<String> customerPhoneNumbers) {
    this.customerPhoneNumbers = customerPhoneNumbers;
  }

  public String getAddedSource() {
    return this.addedSource;
  }

  public CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstName addedSource(
    String addedSource
  ) {
    this.setAddedSource(addedSource);
    return this;
  }

  public void setAddedSource(String addedSource) {
    this.addedSource = addedSource;
  }

  public Integer getMainStarRating() {
    return this.mainStarRating;
  }

  public CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstName mainStarRating(
    Integer mainStarRating
  ) {
    this.setMainStarRating(mainStarRating);
    return this;
  }

  public void setMainStarRating(Integer mainStarRating) {
    this.mainStarRating = mainStarRating;
  }

  public String getComments() {
    return this.comments;
  }

  public CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstName comments(
    String comments
  ) {
    this.setComments(comments);
    return this;
  }

  public void setComments(String comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
  }

  public Boolean getEnjoyedStay() {
    return this.enjoyedStay;
  }

  public CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstName enjoyedStay(
    Boolean enjoyedStay
  ) {
    this.setEnjoyedStay(enjoyedStay);
    return this;
  }

  public void setEnjoyedStay(Boolean enjoyedStay) {
    this.enjoyedStay = enjoyedStay;
  }

  public Boolean getWouldRecommend() {
    return this.wouldRecommend;
  }

  public CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstName wouldRecommend(
    Boolean wouldRecommend
  ) {
    this.setWouldRecommend(wouldRecommend);
    return this;
  }

  public void setWouldRecommend(Boolean wouldRecommend) {
    this.wouldRecommend = wouldRecommend;
  }

  public Instant getHotelAddedDate() {
    return this.hotelAddedDate;
  }

  public CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstName hotelAddedDate(
    Instant hotelAddedDate
  ) {
    this.setHotelAddedDate(hotelAddedDate);
    return this;
  }

  public void setHotelAddedDate(Instant hotelAddedDate) {
    this.hotelAddedDate = hotelAddedDate;
  }

  public String getHotelName() {
    return this.hotelName;
  }

  public CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstName hotelName(
    String hotelName
  ) {
    this.setHotelName(hotelName);
    return this;
  }

  public void setHotelName(String hotelName) {
    this.hotelName = hotelName;
  }

  public String getHotelEmail() {
    return this.hotelEmail;
  }

  public CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstName hotelEmail(
    String hotelEmail
  ) {
    this.setHotelEmail(hotelEmail);
    return this;
  }

  public void setHotelEmail(String hotelEmail) {
    this.hotelEmail = hotelEmail;
  }

  public String getHotelPhoneNumber() {
    return this.hotelPhoneNumber;
  }

  public CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstName hotelPhoneNumber(
    String hotelPhoneNumber
  ) {
    this.setHotelPhoneNumber(hotelPhoneNumber);
    return this;
  }

  public void setHotelPhoneNumber(String hotelPhoneNumber) {
    this.hotelPhoneNumber = hotelPhoneNumber;
  }

  // jhipster-needle-entity-add-getters-setters - JHipster will add getters and setters here

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstName)) {
      return false;
    }
    return (
      id != null &&
      id.equals(((CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstName) o).id)
    );
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    // see https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/
    return getClass().hashCode();
  }

  // prettier-ignore
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstName{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", customerId='" + getCustomerId() + "'" +
            ", customerEmailAddresses='" + getCustomerEmailAddresses() + "'" +
            ", customerPhoneNumbers='" + getCustomerPhoneNumbers() + "'" +
            ", addedSource='" + getAddedSource() + "'" +
            ", mainStarRating=" + getMainStarRating() +
            ", comments='" + getComments() + "'" +
            ", enjoyedStay='" + getEnjoyedStay() + "'" +
            ", wouldRecommend='" + getWouldRecommend() + "'" +
            ", hotelAddedDate='" + getHotelAddedDate() + "'" +
            ", hotelName='" + getHotelName() + "'" +
            ", hotelEmail='" + getHotelEmail() + "'" +
            ", hotelPhoneNumber='" + getHotelPhoneNumber() + "'" +
            "}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to change CassandraType.Name.BIGINT to CassandraType.Name.TIMESTAMP:

In CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstName.java:

```
...

@Column("hotel_added_date")
@CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.TIMESTAMP)
private Instant hotelAddedDate;
...
```

In CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstNameId.java:

```
...

@PrimaryKeyColumn(
  name = "written_date",
  ordinal = 3,
  type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED
)
@CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.TIMESTAMP)
private Instant writtenDate;
...
```